# can a record belong to multiple business units ms dynamics?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am actually handling the access level permissions for records in one of my projects on the basis of business units. If the business unit value of the record and that of the current user is same, only then will the user be granted read access. If the user belongs to a business unit other than the business unit of the record and that record must be visible to that user. But, according to my approach in this case, since the business unit ids are different, the use case fails.

Can a record belong to multiple business units? Or, is there some other way by which I can handle this use case?

Comment: as far as I know in crm-2011 record cannot belong to mulitple business unit.
but you can provide access to users from different unit via 1. Create Team under record owned BU and add user to this newly created Team. 2. Share record to user with specific rights. Note: Share is not the nicest way as it stores all sharing in POA table and it can very quickly explode. let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AnkUser. I will try both ways. Is there anything common in the record and the user tables which can be used as a comparison and give access to the user?

Comment: In any of your security role you can define if record (entity) is accessible on user level, parent child BU level level, BU level and organization level. Take a look at any of your security role and how the access is provided to your table (record)

Comment: Isn't it the same the read access and visibility ?

Comment: What is the difference between the read access and the visible?

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP yes both are the same thing. I just want to handle access to public and private records (articles, cases, etc.).

Comment: @DareToDead Pls read security concepts - https://www.quantacrm.com/2018/06/27/introduction-crm-security-management-microsoft-dynamics-365-for-sales/ it will help for clarity.